# Is there a way to use optgroup in a dc.js selectmenu?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using dc-select-menu to filter a number of graphs successfully.  I am decorating the selects with bootstrap-selectpicker.

I've come across a situation where I need to apply optgroups, which would make better sense to the end user - rather than creating another select.

I've tried to add the optgroup tag in the div for the dc-select.

I've tried changing the div to a select.

I've tried appending the optgroup.

relevant code...

```
            var dept = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Department });
            var deptGp = dept.group();

            var deptGroupLabel = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.DepartmentGroup; });
            var deptLabel = deptGroupLabel.group();

            var depts = "<optgroup label=" + deptLabel + ">" + "</optgroup>";

          deptSelect
            .dimension(dept)
            .group(deptGp)
            .multiple(true)
            .title(function(d) { return d.key })
            .controlsUseVisibility(true);

        deptSelect
            .on('postRender', function() {
                deptSelect.select('.dc-select-menu').attr('data-actions-box', 'true');

                $('#deptSelect .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
                    liveSearch: true,
                    liveSearchStyle: 'contains',
                    showTick: true,
                    selectOnTab: true,
                    virtualScroll: 8,
                    doneButton: true
                });
              })
                .on('postRedraw', function() {
                $('#deptSelect .dc-select-menu').selectpicker('refresh');
            });

            $('#deptSelect .dc-select-menu').append(depts);
```

I would like to see the deptLabel as the optgroup, with the corresponding departments following.

Comment: Isn't the idea of an option group that each group is independent? In crossfilter terms. this would make each optgroup its own crossfilter dimension and group, and that would be difficult to squeeze into a dc.js chart. (It would be a composite selectMenu, I guess, ugh.)

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify that.  Yes, it is a .dc-select-menu that I am using.  (Decorating with bootstrap-selectpicker. I really only need it as a label, not necessarily selectable. I am trying to avoid adding another select to add clarity to a very long list.  Since, I have tried adding a data-* as an attribute to grab a hold of that, but it is only attaching to the first dc-select-option.

Comment: AH, I just re-read your comment and better understand your point.  (Sorry, should have slowed down a minute).  So a composite selectMenu, just like putting together composite charts?

Comment: That was a feeble joke, sorry. I don't think the selectMenu as it's currently written could handle more than one group/dimension. So I think you might be able to get optgroup headers to show, but controlling two filters at once would be hard.

Comment: Yeah.  I am finding that (controlling two filters part). Right now, I am having trouble getting optgroup to append.  Thanks for looking at this anyhow.  I appreciate it! And thank you for all you are doing with this library - it is fantastic!

Comment: You're welcome! I just tried and I was able to add optgroups by removing elements and then putting them back inside of new optgroup elements. However, the selectMenu got confused by this, and started dropping things once filtering changed the list of items. So I think your best bet (if you're willing to put in the effort) is to hack on the source. [This component isn't very complicated.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/select-menu.js)

Comment: Will give it a shot.  Thank you again!